# how rank change with replacing $a_{11}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n×n$ matrix. matrix $B$ is obtained from $A$ by replacing $a_{11}$ by $a_{11}+1$ keeping order unchanged. How is rank get affected?

I deem that rank(B) must be greater than 1 . I really don't know how to approach this question. M just guessing . Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: This is not true: Consider the matrix $A$ with $a_{11} = -1$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ for $(i, j) \neq (1, 1)$. Then, $\textrm{rank} B = 0$.

Comment: Than what is rank of B ? Should $rank(B) \leq{rank(A)}$.

Comment: Not necessarily. If $A = 0$, then $B \neq 0$, so $\rank A = 0 < \rank B$. Do you mean to ask, what is a sharp bound on $\rank B$ in terms of $\rank A$?

Answer (score 3):

using subaddivity property $rank(A+C)\leqslant rank(A)+rank(C)$, where $A+C=B$, so $C$ - is a matrix with one non-zero element $c_{11}=1$, and so $rank(C)=1$. So, $$rank(B)\leqslant rank(A)+1$$

Comment: Note that we can similarily prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A) - 1 \leq \operatorname{B}$ (by examining $A = B-C$ instead of $B = A+C$), thus have a bound on either side of $B$. It's not difficult to construct examples of both bounds being attained.

Comment: @Arthur So the final conclusion is that by a changing any one element we can change the rank +1,0 or -1?

Comment: @Widawensen Yes, that is the conclusion. In fact, changing elements freely within a single row or a single column has the same effect.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for the confirmation. It's a very interesting fact unknown previously to me.

Comment: @Widawensen It can also be explained directly from linear indepencencies. The rank of a matrix is the maximal number of column vectors (or row vectors, if you are so inclined) of the matrix that forms a linearly independent set. If the column (or row) that you change is part of all such sets, then changing it at worst means that you have to remove it from the set, thus decreasing the rank by $1$. If there is such a maximal set without your column in it, then changing that column can at best let you include it, thus increasing the rank by 1.